# Creating dictionary in VBScript

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

I created dictionary by this way:

```
Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

This is ordinary dictionary. It is looks like

```
key1    value1
key2    value2
```

After that I added this code:

```
Dim var
var = "test"

Set d(var) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d(var).Add "x", "ValueX"
WScript.Echo d(var).Item("x")
```

And got "ValueX"

What is this d(var)? How it relates to the dictionary d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary `d` contains a nested dictionary in the key `test` to which you add a key `x` with the value `ValueX`. It probably becomes clearer when you visualize the data structure (you can use my helper function [`DumpData()`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/dumpdata.shtml) for that):

```
>>> import "C:\Temp\DataDumper.vbs"
>>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>>> WScript.Echo DumpData(d)
{}
>>> var = "test"
>>> Set d(var) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>>> WScript.Echo DumpData(d)
{
        "test" => {}
}
>>> d(var).Add "x", "ValueX"
>>> WScript.Echo DumpData(d)
{
        "test" => {
                "x" => "ValueX"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a dictionary. It contains a key ("test") - value (`d("test")`/`d.Item("test")`) pair. The value of this pair happens to be a dictionary too. That contains a pair "x" - "ValueX".